# calling a method outside Onclick listener method in android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am using following tutorial to send message to arduino via Bluetooth. (see LEDOnOff.java code)

http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/arduino-to-android-turning-led-on-and.html

I want to make changes to this code such that the `sendData()` method is called as soon as the app starts but when i call `sendData()` method outside onClick listener of the button, app crashes with following errors.(I called `sendData("1")` in `onCreate` method; outside onClick listener of button).

The code that i used is:

```
package com.example.ledonoff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LEDOnOff extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "LEDOnOff";

  Button btnOn, btnOff;

  private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private OutputStream outStream = null;

  // Well known SPP UUID
  private static final UUID MY_UUID =
      UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // Insert your bluetooth devices MAC address
  private static String address = "20:13:10:16:09:19";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "In onCreate()");

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();
    sendData("1");  //this line is added by me and i have removed onclick method


  }



  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onResume - Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
      btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting to Remote...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Creating Socket...");

    try {
      outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
      try {
        outStream.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    try     {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on

    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth Not supported. Aborting.");
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth is enabled...");
      } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
    }
  }

  private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    msg.show();
    finish();
  }


  public void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");

    try {
      outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
      if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
        msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
      msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

      errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
    }
  }

}

**Log-cat :**

    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886):  
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886):  
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G7102_4.4.2_0033
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886):  
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886):  
    02-14 10:30:36.002: I/SELinux(1886): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
    02-14 10:30:36.002: E/SELinux(1886): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
    02-14 10:30:36.002: E/dalvikvm(1886): >>>>> Normal User
    02-14 10:30:36.002: E/dalvikvm(1886): >>>>> com.example.ledonoff [ userId:0 | appId:10288 ]
    02-14 10:30:36.002: E/SELinux(1886): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
    02-14 10:30:36.002: D/dalvikvm(1886): Late-enabling CheckJNI
    02-14 10:30:36.162: D/LEDOnOff(1886): In onCreate()
    02-14 10:30:36.292: D/LEDOnOff(1886): ...Bluetooth is enabled...
    02-14 10:30:36.292: D/LEDOnOff(1886): ...Sending data: 1...
    02-14 10:30:36.292: D/AndroidRuntime(1886): Shutting down VM
    02-14 10:30:36.292: W/dalvikvm(1886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4181eda0)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): Process: com.example.ledonoff, PID: 1886
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ledonoff/com.example.ledonoff.LEDOnOff}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.example.ledonoff.LEDOnOff.sendData(LEDOnOff.java:180)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at com.example.ledonoff.LEDOnOff.onCreate(LEDOnOff.java:52)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
    02-14 10:30:36.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     ... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me with doing so? tell me if there is any other way to implement my thought.

Comment: please show related part of code

Comment: while posting questions on SO, you should also post code so that people can see where the issue is, along with logcat output!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreate() is called before onResume().  The way you have it coded currently your outstream is null.  Look at the Android lifecycle.

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity